# How to fetch list of all the product item from tally server using php

Tags: php, tally

I have to fetch product item list from the paritcular table list
from the tally server using php code.So in my tally server i have
the few tables like stock item,stock groups,stock category in my
inventory master.In my stock item table i have approx more than
3000 items in the list with product details,for this i have also
got the php code using curl method but that list is not coming
from stock item table it is coming from somewhere else.Please help
me how i can achieve this.

```
<?php

$res_str =<<<XML
 <ENVELOPE>
 <HEADER>
 <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
 </HEADER>
 <BODY>
 <EXPORTDATA>
 <REQUESTDESC>
 <REPORTNAME>stock category summary</REPORTNAME>
 </REQUESTDESC>
 </EXPORTDATA>
 </BODY>
 </ENVELOPE>
XML;


$url = "http://localhost:9000/";

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    "xmlRequest=" . $res_str);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        //echo '<pre>';
        //var_dump($data);die;

        curl_close($ch);
        // get the xml object 
    $object = simplexml_load_string( $data );
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($object);die;
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First , Getting All Items from Tally at once is not a good practice , unless you have super fast server, as it slow downs or even closes Tally

First Get List of IDs of objects you want and Iterate through the list and get object one by one

You can use below xml to get List of Stock Item - MasterID's and GUID'S

If You want all data at once just **add `<NATIVEMETHOD>*</NATIVEMETHOD>`**

If you want StockCategory and StockGroup Change type to accordingly

Ex: for StockCategory - `<TYPE>StockCategory</TYPE>`

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
    <ID>Custom List of StockItems</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES />
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="Yes" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Custom List of StockItems">
                    <TYPE>StockItem</TYPE>
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>MasterID</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>GUID</NATIVEMETHOD>
                </COLLECTION>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```

To get StockItem or any master by MasterID - use below xml,

If you want to get by GUID, you can change filter accordingly

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
    <ID>CustColl</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
             <!-- * Static variables like scfrom,svto,svexport format will not work -->
         
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustColl">
                    <TYPE>masters</TYPE>
                    <!-- * will fetch all fields if you want specific fields you can specify -->
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    <FILTERS>filter</FILTERS>
                </COLLECTION>
                 <!-- You can  change filter to other than name also -->
                <!--to get any Master based on name  replace $Masterid with $Name  -->
                <!--Replace 1122 with Masterid you want to search -->
                <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="filter">$Masterid=1122</SYSTEM>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```